# Android Studio: Code changes not reflected when pressing run app even with instant run off

Tags: android, android-studio, build

Since a couple of days code changes are not reflected when I press run app (^r). I now have to run my app twice before the actual code change is applied.

Yes I could clean my project of course, but I wouldn't want to clean my project for every time I want to check code changes. Also Instant Run is disabled so it shouldn't have anything to do with that.

I am running on Android Studio 2.3.3
- kotlin 1.1.3
- gradle 2.3.3
- buildTools 26.0.0

Is there anything I can do here to get this issue fixed?

edit:
- changes are in kotlin files as well as in xml files, both need 2 app starts before app gets updated to latest code changes :s. Tried invalidate cache and restart but that isn't solving the problem...

Comment: Are your changes in java/xml files? Try doing a invalidate caches/restart option to check if problem still persists

Comment: @manishkumar changes are in kotlin files as well as in xml files, both need 2 app starts before app gets updated to latest code changes :s. Tried invalidate cache and restart but that isn't solving the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem when i change html files. Studio cannot recognize changes in html files and does not re-deploy application.Uninstall the application on device and then run app.It should work.

Comment: Even that is not working :) Well that looks like Android Studio is somehow caching something and is always one build behind when deploying the build to device